# Trying to replicate a nomogram plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to replicate this plot:

[image: My desired plot]

I can set the colors with

```
 scale_color_gradient2()
```

But I do not find how I can format it nicely to have only the x-axis showing and the title nicely centered. I already tested a bit with following example:

```
library("reshape")
library("scales")
min <- 10
max <- 200
a <- seq(from = min, to = max, by = 5)

b <- 1:length(a)
b <- rep("var_a", length(a))
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))
df <- df[order(df$a),]

ggplot(df,aes(x = b, y = b,fill = as.numeric(a))) + 
  scale_fill_gradient2() +
  geom_bar(position = "fill",stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_color_gradient2(midpoint=mid, low="blue", mid="white",
                        high="red", space ="Lab" )+
  ggtitle("test title")
```

That resulted in:

[image]

Comment: Please provide reproducible data and code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I tried to mimic your plot example.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x = b, y = 1:nrow(df), fill = as.numeric(a))) + 
  scale_fill_gradient2() +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity", width = 1) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_color_gradient2(midpoint=mid, low="blue", mid="white",high="red", space ="Lab" )+
  ggtitle("test title") +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "") +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  guides(fill = FALSE)
```

[image]